# Groovy, too many open files and withStream closure

Tags: groovy

I got unexpected 'too many open files' error when I use code like:

```
new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)).withStream { os -> 
   try {
       os.write(...)
       os.flush()
   } catch (Exception ex) {
       log.error(...) 
   }
}
```

I thought that withStream supposes that stream should be auto-closed.. 
Could you please advise why this may happen?

Comment: Yes, it is auto-closed. So maybe the problem lies somewhere else. Paste a full example to investigate.

Comment: Opal is right. You can also replace your first line with `file.withStream { os ->`

Answer (score 0):

Your operating system places a limit on the number of open file descriptors that a process may have at any given time. This error comes up when your application exceeds that limit. And most likely your stream wasn't able to auto-close. I suggest you view which files are being kept open.

For Linux:

```
lsof -p <jvm pid>
```

For Windows you can probably try some utility e.g. [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

There are also ways to increase the per-process file descriptor limit. Please see `ulimit` for UNIX like platforms.